# how to create own models and map them on table

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've created diagram from my database. I've just connected to my db via visual studio and created .edmx model. Than I've auto generated context so I have classes with my data models.

Auto generation works ok. But can I (and if I can how to do that) create files manualy and than map them on tables so when I`ll use linq to query my db my app will automaticly created objects based on rows ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called `code first` and you can [get an intro here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620).